# Framework for creating executable to be executed from the business rules in py-spark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, expression, dynamicquery

I have a dataframe df with below sample values.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType, LongType, StringType, StructType, StructField,BooleanType
import os
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import datetime
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,IntegerType,ArrayType
from pyspark.sql import Row

l = [('test',1,0,1,0),('prod',0,1,0,1),('local',1,0,1,0)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
sdf = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(col1=x[0], col2=int(x[1]),col3=int(x[2]),col4=int(x[3]),col5=int(x[4])))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sdf)

-----+----+----+----+----+
| col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+-----+----+----+----+----+
| test|   1|   0|   1|   0|
| prod|   0|   1|   0|   1|
|local|   1|   0|   1|   0|
+-----+----+----+----+----+
```

Also have some business rules as below. As of now this is saved as a meta  data in a dictionary.(However rules metadata can be kept something like  :agg_level,agg_function,transformation,source,source_column also)

```
 features = {
  "col6": F.when(F.col('col2') > 0,F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
  "col7": F.when(F.col('col3') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
  "col8": F.when(F.col('col4') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
  "col9": F.when(F.col('col5') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
}
```

I want to create a function say , df_extract() , which dynamically generate the executable code as below . This should return the below query to be executed(not as a dataframe)

```
df1 = df_extract(df,col6,col7,col8,col9)
df1 = **df.filter('col1 = "test"') \
    .withColumn('col6', F.when(F.col('col2') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col7', F.when(F.col('col3') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col8', F.when(F.col('col4') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col9', F.when(F.col('col5') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))**
```

When calling with three features, only  three features should be present in the returned query and so on.

```
df1 = df_extract(df,col6,col7,col8) 
df1 = **df.filter('col1 = "test"') \
    .withColumn('col6', F.when(F.col('col2') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col7', F.when(F.col('col3') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col8', F.when(F.col('col4') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))**
```

finally with no features , all  features should be there  in the expression/query.

```
df1 = df_extract(df)
df1 = **df.filter('col1 = "test"') \
    .withColumn('col6', F.when(F.col('col2') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col7', F.when(F.col('col3') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col8', F.when(F.col('col4') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('col9', F.when(F.col('col5') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))**
```

Is this possible anyhow , at-least by creating sql table in pyspark. N-number of such transformation rules will be associated with each each dataframe and the function should be capable of returning the definition dynamically.

feel tired of thinking a solution for it.

Comment: I like that object `F` who allows `.when().otherwise()` :D. Where is it from?

Comment: :) I just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I thought is to use the rules as case condition.

```
   journey_features = {
      "Rules":{
      "col6": "case when col2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col6",
      "col7": "case when col3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col7",
      "col8": "case when col4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col8",
      "col9": "case when col5 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col9"
      },
      "filter":"col1 == 'test'"
      }
```

The extract_feature() function is created as below to use the rules as expression.

```
    def extract_feature(df : DataFrame,*featurenames):
  retrieved_features = ""
  for featurename in featurenames:
    if featurename  in journey_features.get('Rules'):
      retrieved_features += "'" + str(journey_features.get('Rules')[featurename]) +"'" + ","
  retrieved_features = retrieved_features.rstrip(',')
  if journey_features['filter']:
    filter_feature = ".filter({df}.".format(df=df) + str(journey_features['filter']) + ")"
  else:
    filte_feature = ""
  return "{0}{1}.selectExpr({2})".format(df,filter_feature,retrieved_features)
```

And pass the df and pass , features to the function.

```
extract_feature('df','col6','col7')
```

The result is

```
Out[139]: "df.filter(df.measurement_group == 'test').selectExpr('case when col2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col6','case when col3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col7')"
```

can assign to the dataframe usig eval function

```
df1 = eval(extract_feature('df','col6','col7'))
```